# Dense subspaces of $L^\infty(\Omega\times\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, product-space, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R$ be open and bounded.  For **continuous** functions $C(\Omega\times\Omega)$, the Stone-Weierstrass theorem shows that the *products* $a(x)b(y)$ of univariate continuous functions in $C(\Omega)$ span a dense subspace.  However, for **bounded** functions in $L^\infty(\Omega\times\Omega)$, the only subspace I can think of is spanned by the *indicator functions* $\chi_A(x,y)$, where $A\subset\Omega\times\Omega$ is measurable.

**My question:** is there a more convenient dense subspace of $L^\infty(\Omega\times\Omega)$?  In particular, do the products $a(x)b(y)$ of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ functions span a dense subspace?

**Motivation:** I am considering the $L^2$ continuity of pseudo-differential operators with $L^\infty$ symbols $a$:
$$
Au(x)=\int e^{i(x-y)\cdot\xi}a(x,y,\xi)u(y)dyd\xi.
$$
If $a(x,y,\xi)\sim \sum a(x)b(y)c(\xi)$, such as if $a(x,y,\xi)$ is bounded and continuous, then $L^2$ continuity follows immediately from the properties of $L^\infty$ multiplier operators.  But without this product structure, I am not sure where to go.

Comment: Can you approximate the characteristic functions of measurable sets of $\Omega\times\Omega$ by such finite linear combinations?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I believe yes in an $L^p$ space if $p<\infty$, but I'm not sure about if $p=\infty$.

Comment: What would you do in the p case that doesn't work here?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I recall that if you approximate $A$ by a disjoint union $A_i$ of rectangles (in the symmetric difference pseudometric), then $\int |\chi_A-\sum\chi_{A_i}|^p\to 0$ as $\bigcup A_i\to A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L^\infty$ functions can be approximated by simple functions, i.e., finite linear combinations of characteristic functions.

see [Uniform convergence of simple functions to a bounded function $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503416/uniform-convergence-of-simple-functions-to-a-bounded-function-f)

The function 
$$
f(x,y) =\begin{cases}
1 & x\le y\\
0 & x>y \\
\end{cases}
$$
cannot be approximated by functions of the type $a(x)b(y)$. Let me consider $f$ as measurable function on $[0,1]^2$. In order to have $\sup_{(x,y)}|f(x,y)-a(x)b(y)|<\epsilon$ it is necessary to have this for the corners of the square, i.e.,
$$
|1-a(0)b(0)|,|1-a(0)b(1)|,|1-a(1)b(1)|, |a(1)b(0)|< \epsilon.
$$
This implies that all values $a(0),b(0),a(1),b(1)$ are not zero. And $a(0)$ is close to $b(0)^{-1}$, $b(1)^{-1}$, $a(1)$. Hence $a(1)b(0)$ is close to $1$, contradiction.